# ssh through python script

Tags: python, ssh

this is how my python script looks like

```
import os
command = 'ssh testServer'
os.system(command)
```

it gives me following error

```
[Sun Aug 17 11:07:30 Adam@testServer:~/] $ python test.py
ld.so.1: ssh: fatal: relocation error: file /usr/bin/ssh: symbol SUNWcry_installed: referenced symbol not found
Killed
```

Ssh command works fine when I execute it from command line. Only when I try it from within a python script using either os/subprocess module, it complains with the above error.

Comment: The problem [seems](https://community.oracle.com/thread/1908619?start=0&tstart=0) to be related to the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable. Could you post the output of `ldd /usr/bin/ssh` and `echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH` both from the command line and from a python system call.

Comment: libsocket.so.1 =>/lib/libsocket.so.1
libnsl.so.1 =>/lib/libnsl.so.1
libz.so.1 =>/opt/svn/current/lib/libz.so.1
libz.so.1 (SUNW_1.1) =>  (version not found)
libcrypto.so.0.9.7 => /usr/sfw/lib/libcrypto.so.0.9.7
libgss.so.1 =>/usr/lib/libgss.so.1
libc.so.1 =>/lib/libc.so.1
libmp.so.2 =>/lib/libmp.so.2
libmd.so.1 =>/lib/libmd.so.1
libscf.so.1 =>/lib/libscf.so.1
libcmd.so.1 =>/lib/libcmd.so.1
libdoor.so.1 =>/lib/libdoor.so.1
libuutil.so.1 => /lib/libuutil.so.1
libgen.so.1 =>/lib/libgen.so.1
libcrypto_extra.so.0.9.7 =>  /usr/sfw/lib/libcrypto_extra.so.0.9.7
libm.so.2 =>/lib/libm.so.2

Comment: echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH 
/opt/svn/current/lib

Comment: and what is $LD_LIBRARY_PATH when running python?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use `os.system`, you should use a [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html):

Like in your case:

```
 bshCmd = "ssh testServer"
 import subprocess
 process = subprocess.Popen(bshCmd.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
 output = process.communicate()[0]
```

Please let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: Hello @cartridgemeadow.. I used both os/subprocess and see the same result. I specified this in my question originally. 
Just to confirm I used your code but see the same error again

Comment: hmm...@user2812714, could you try running "unset $LD_LIBRARY_PATH" before you run ssh; and before you unset it, be SURE to echo it and copy it's contents from bash into a text file, so that you could reset it later

Comment: also, if you run "ssh testServer" from bash, does it work? if it does, then this is a python issue that has to do with property settings and we could find a work around!

Comment: I get this when I try to unset
unset $LD_LIBRARY_PATH 
-bash: unset: `/opt/svn/current/lib': not a valid identifier

Comment: yes as mentioned in the question, it does work when I execute it from bash.

Comment: sorry, could you please do "unset LD_LIBRARY_PATH" without the "$", and let me know it's okay?

Comment: @user2812714, i believe this should fix it, could you please try it and then run the test.py script

Comment: I was hoping that would help but it didn't. 
XXX: unset LD_LIBRARY_PATH
XXX: $ python test.py
ld.so.1: ssh: fatal: relocation error: file /usr/bin/ssh: symbol SUNWcry_installed: referenced symbol not found

Comment: ugh okay. Shooting from the hip, the forum that Andrew Johnson posted says this fixed it for them:>>>>>>> LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/sfw/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH ; export LD_LIBRARY_PATH

in the users .profile file.<<<<<<<<<<<<

Could you give that a try?

Comment: what do you mean by export LD_LIBRARY_PATH in the users .profile  ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59474/discussion-between-user2812714-and-cartridgemeadow).

Answer (score 1):

So your ssh relies on a library that is located in /opt/svn/current/lib: "libz.so.1 =>/opt/svn/current/lib/libz.so.1 libz.so.1 (SUNW_1.1)". It finds this library by looking at the environment variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. This variable is not preserved by the os.system call in python.

```
import os
import subprocess
command = 'ssh testServer'
subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, env=os.environ)
```

Answer (score 0):

The os.system has many problems and subprocess is a much better way to executing unix command. Use This recipe:

```
import subprocess
ssh = subprocess.Popen(["ssh", "%s" % HOST, COMMAND],
                           shell=False,
                           stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                           stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Comment: I used both subprocess/os as mentioned in the question. I still see the same issue

Comment: see this link http://python-for-system-administrators.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ssh.html

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using an ssh automation package instead? Something like https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ssh/1.7.8